# Why is my MIPS program not printing the desired register correctly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I've attached the code below. The goal if this program is to both iterate through each element of the array *list* as well as set the register `$t0` to 1 if any of the elements are equal to 81, and to 0 if otherwise. I am trying to test the code by way of printing the value of `$t0`, but the program is ending without printing anything.

```
.data

list:   .word 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, 81, 7, 8, 9

.text

main:

la $a1, list
li $a3, 81
move $t0, $zero

li $t4, 10
li $t5, 0

j loop

loop:

bge $t4, $t5, end

lw $a2, 0($a1)

seq $t1, $a2, $a3
add $t0, $t0, $t1

addi $a1, $a1, 4
addi $t5, $t5, 1

j loop

end:

sgt $t0, $t0, $zero

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall
```

Comment: Where exactly is the code that should print anything?

Comment: @Jester It should be in ``end:``.

Comment: Oops I assumed that was an `exit` syscall :) Note that `bge $t4, $t5, end` is reversed, since `$t4` is 10 and `$t5` is 0 so it will jump immediately and should print 0 and it does here.

Comment: @Jester What a silly mistake of mine! Thank you.